# A function that grows more slowly than ln(n) but is not a constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

I have two algorithms. One is returning an output that, when the output is $n$, is roughly of the value $\ln(n)$.

The other one is returning a value of the following sizes:

| Vaue of n | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 2.1275 |
| 25 | 2.5816 |
| 50 | 2.8537 |
| 75 | 3.0603 |
| 100 | 3.1572 |
| 150 | 3.3311 |
| 200 | 3.4380 |
| 250 | 3.5138 |
| 300 | 3.5726 |
| 400 | 3.6932 |

So the output of this function is clearly below $O(\ln(n))$, but it is also growing with $n$ and not converging to a constant.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me make a good conjecture for the growth rate of this algorithm and point me to any series in maths that has a similar growth rate. Note that $\ln(\ln(n))$ is too small to be a good approximation, but the ratio $\text{output}/\ln(\ln(n))$ seems to be slowly converging. The ratio $\text{output}/\sqrt{\ln(n)}$ seems diverging.

Comment: Functions which grow more slowly than $\ln(n)$ are (for example) $\sqrt{\ln n}, \ln\ln n, \ln\ln\ln n, \ldots$. I doubt that an educated guess can be made from just four samples.

Comment: Ok I am adding more values

Comment: Or maybe give some information about the algorithm?

Comment: *"So the output of this function is clearly below $O(\ln(n))$"*. How so? From input 10 to 100 the out goes up by $\approx 1$, which is consistant with logarithmic growth. Strictly speaking there is also no way to conclude *"clearly below $O(\ln(n))$"* from a finite list (especially a list as short as the given one), since $O$-notation is an asymptotic statement.

Comment: @Vincent The algorithm is not super easy to describe, but if you are interested is here https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053114001446

Comment: interesting subject, school choice!  But what are the n and output here?

Comment: n is the number of school and students. output is average rank.

Comment: @fox please edit the explanation and link into the question.